# unrecognized option: --diagnostics-file in Mallet

Tags: text-mining, lda, topic-modeling, diagnostics, mallet

I am using LDA in mallet to explore my data. I do not have training and test data. I just use it for clustering my data. 
I would like to use a number of useful diagnostic measures provided by Mallet. but when I use this query:

```
bin\mallet train-topics --input doc500.mallet --num-topics 40 --num-top-words  50 --optimize-interval 10 --output-state doc500topic40-state.gz --output-topic-keys doc500topic40-keys.txt --output-doc-topics  doc500topic40-composition.txt --topic-word-weights-file  doc500topic40-word-weights.txt --diagnostics-file doc500topic40_diagnostics.xml
```

then I get this Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Unrecognized option 16: --diagnostics-file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagnostics file option is relatively new. Make sure that you are using version 2.0.8.